# How can I add the RTL version to Quild Editor? in vuejs 3

Tags: vuejs3, text-editor, quill

i want use Quild editor Bubble Version for rtl project

I read the Quild documentation but did not get the result

This is really important to me. If you have an editorial suggestion other than Quil, please tell me (it has a bubble version).

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic setup you need:

```
.ql-editor {
  direction: rtl !important;
  text-align: right !important;
}
.ql-editor ol, .ql-editor ul {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
}
.ql-editor ol li:not(.ql-direction-rtl), .ql-editor ul li:not(.ql-direction-rtl) {
    /* padding-left: 1.5rem; */
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
}
.ql-editor li:not(.ql-direction-rtl)::before {
    margin-left: 0.3rem !important;
    margin-right: -1.5rem !important;
    text-align: left !important;
}
```